# Wait for animation of multiple elements to end?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a collapsable list, when a user clicks on an item I collapse all other items before expanding the clicked item. I want to wait until all elements are collapsed to expand the item but I don't know how to do it. (right not it all happens simultaneusly)

How can I wait until all items collapse before running the rest of the code?

```
    $(".content").slideUp();
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
    $(".content").slideUp(function () {
        alert("done");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.promise()` method on a collection of elements:

```
$('.content').promise().then(function() {
     // all animations are finished
});
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

> The `.promise()` method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is
>   resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection,
>   queued or not, have ended.
>
> By default, type is "fx", which means the returned Promise is resolved
>   when all animations of the selected elements have completed.